# Custom [Authorize] message on 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, authorize

I need to deliver custom "not authorized" message in different languages, instead of the default "Authorization has been denied for this request". I'm using Owin as authentication and the [Authorize] attribute for ApiControllers/methods. I know that this could be done with a custom autorization filter, but it seems an overkill situation just to change the message sent to the client.

Is there a simpler way of changing the message or should I stick to a custom authorize filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately It is not possible.

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs), one option would be to create a new custom Authorize attribute, inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute`. You then would only need to override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method, and replace with your own. The rest of the methods would be still handled by the base `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
  public class MyCustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
      protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
            {
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
            }

                actionContext.Response =
                actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                                      HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
                                      "My Un-Authorized Message");
      }
    }
```