# How to capture a SecurityTokenExpiredException in OWIN middleware?

Tags: c#, .net, owin, .net-framework-version, refresh-token

I have a Web API with OWIN that uses `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` (.Net Framework 4.5.2) to validate authentication tokens.

While following [this excellent article](https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/) by Rui Figueiredo in order to add a Refresh Token ability to the API, it seems I don't have `JwtBearerEvents` in OWIN. E.g. This code works for me in ASP.NET Core (in ConfigureServices):

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = GetDefaultValidationParameters();
    x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

I can't seem to grasp how to achieve the same using the OWIN pipeline. What I've tried is inserting a middleware in ConfigureAuth:

```
private static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder pApp)
{
    pApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        try
        {
            await next.Invoke();
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException)
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token - Expired", new[] { "true" });
            throw;
        }
    });
    var issuer = "issuer";
    var audience = "all";
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MySecretKey");
    pApp.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
            IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new IIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider(issuer, key)
            },
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters,
            TokenHandler = new CustomJWTTokenHandler()
        });
}
```

But to no avail. The 401 status comes without the Token-Expired header in this case.

Does anybody have any pointers on how to do this properly in Katana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Following the lead of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505523/how-to-return-custom-message-if-authorize-fails-in-webapi) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378644/custom-authorize-message-on-401?rq=1) I added a custom authorization attribute to my base controller, i.e:

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        var ctx = actionContext;
        var token = ctx.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
        var handler = new CustomJWTTokenHandler();
        if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && handler.TokenHasExpired(token))
        {
            ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
        }
    }
}
```

and implemented an expiration check in my `CustomJWTTokenHandler` class like this:

```
public bool TokenHasExpired(string tokenString)
{
    var token = ReadToken(tokenString);
    var hasExpired = token.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow;
    return hasExpired;
}
```

HTH